# Discretization of continuous model with white noise to use Kalman filter later

Tags: dynamical-systems, matlab, continuity, kalman-filter, discrete-calculus

I have this system  which describes dynamics of a car in 2D space. The dynamics are governed by Newton's law *g(t) = ma(t)*. The final task is to use Kalman filter on discretized system to estimate it's position and velocity. The measurements are based on GPS signal with some covariance.

Unfortunately, I already got stucked at the beginning. I dont know how to incorporate the **G** matrix with *w* and *e* into discretization. Based on what I've learned, it should meant process and measurement noise.
Therefore it doesnt effect the dynamics of the system itself and I shouldnt count it during the discretization. Am I right? However based on the assignment, I should somehow edit w and e for the discretized model. In that case, why **Gc** dissappears? Of course, then the different time steps confuse me as well :(

In order to achieve this result, can I just use ss function in MATLAB to create system and then use c2d function to discretize it?
I just look at this already two days and since I'm just overall confused about the course of actions, I havent moved a bit.

[Description of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTI7k.png)

If I could ask you for some advice how to proceed I would really appreciate a lot!! Thanks in advance